# Grouping By View in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

How to unite several same data / data duplication by example in the picture below

IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1cHC.jpg

And this my Query:

```
SELECT cl.client_group,
       cl.NAME,
       vw.CLASS,
       vw.buscat,
       vw.currency,
       vw.sum_insured,
       vw.client_premium,
       vw.net_income,
       vw.client
  FROM vw_ans_pol_coingrpibs vw, client cl, client_grp cgrp
 WHERE (vw.CLIENT = cl.CLIENT(+))
   AND (cl.CLIENT_GROUP = cgrp.CLIENT_GROUP(+))
   AND vw.CLOSING_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
       TO_DATE('15/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
 ORDER BY vw.CURRENCY, vw.CLIENT, vw.CLASS
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What *does* your query return, and what *should* it return (please don't just post an image link - add sample data to your question)?

Comment: You aren't using the cgrp table. Missing WHERE or HAVING conditions? 
Please describe the data and results.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you well, you did most of the job, you only have to group by and you're done:

```
SELECT X.NAME, X.CLASS,
       SUM(X.sum_insured) sum_insured,
       SUM(X.client_premium) client_premium,
       SUM(X.net_income) net_income
from
(
    SELECT cl.client_group,
           cl.NAME,
           vw.CLASS,
           vw.buscat,
           vw.currency,
           vw.sum_insured,
           vw.client_premium,
           vw.net_income,
           vw.client
      FROM vw_ans_pol_coingrpibs vw, client cl, client_grp cgrp
     WHERE (vw.CLIENT = cl.CLIENT(+))
       AND (cl.CLIENT_GROUP = cgrp.CLIENT_GROUP(+))
       AND vw.CLOSING_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
           TO_DATE('15/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
) X
GROUP BY X.NAME, X.CLASS
```